# Unable to create report on AuthSession Object

Tags: reporting, analytics, sales-cloud

We have requirement to identify list of users logged in to Salesforce currently(In other words, who have active session).  We understand [AuthSession Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm) has details of active session users but we are unable to create any report on this object(It is not available for selection) despite documentation saying so (Please see below screen capture)
[image]

Any pointers towards the solution are highly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: i know you said report but does `Setup | User Sessions` get what you need?

Comment: @cropredy We are suggesting the same approach to create list view for monitoring current logged in users, Is it possible to create standard report like the document is suggesting? Unable to do it?

Comment: I don't know re: standard report - you could write a screen flow that did the query and presented the results in a table so users other than admins could see it; or build a VF page that you added to a dashboard component

Comment: Thank you so much @cropredy